# Derivative of minimization by a variable in the equality constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

If I know $a^1(c)$, $a^2(c)$, and $a^3(c)$, and that

$a(c) = min \left[ a^1(c^1)+a^2(c^2)+a^3(c^3)\right]$

subject to

$c^1+c^2+c^3=c$

can I write an expression for $\frac{da}{dc}$?

Follow-up: Is the solution simpler if we are dealing with convex functions?

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009330/derivative-of-a-minimizer-by-a-variable-in-a-constraint) one.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what is the $\min$ about in the definition of $a(c)$.

Comment: $c^1$, $c^2$ and $c^3$ are chosen such that $a^1(c^1)+a^2(c^2)+a^3(c^3)$ is minimized, while also satisfying $c^1+c^2+c^3=c$.

Comment: Well, if it's convex then you can use the KKT conditions to find the minimizer.

Comment: Finding the minimizer is not the problem, I am interested in the derivative of the minimized quantity by a variable in the constraint.